# How to save my interval time using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built the following jQuery for image animation in a loop using `setInterval()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var runAnimate1 = true;
    var runAnimate2 = false;
    var runAnimate3 = false;

    setInterval(function() {
        if (runAnimate1) {
            $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
                'display': 'inline-block',
                'margin-left': '220px',
                'margin-bottom': '20px'
            }, 500, function() {
                $('.1st').animate({
                    'opacity': '0'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $('.1st').animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    })
                })
            }).fadeOut();
            $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({
                'margin-bottom': '0px',
                'margin-left': '-140px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                runAnimate1 = false;
                runAnimate2 = true;
                runAnimate3 = false;
            }).fadeOut('slow');
        }

        if (runAnimate2) {
            $(".2nd").fadeIn('slow').animate({
                'margin-left': '150px',
                'margin-bottom': '2px'
            }, 600, function() {
                $('.1st').animate({
                    'opacity': '0'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $('.1st').animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    }, 1000)
                })
            }).fadeOut();
            $(".2nd").fadeIn('slow').animate({
                'margin-bottom': '0px',
                'margin-left': '-150px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                runAnimate1 = false;
                runAnimate2 = false;
                runAnimate3 = true
            }).fadeOut('slow');
        }

        if (runAnimate3) {
            $('.3rd').fadeIn('slow').animate({
                'display': 'inline-block',
                'margin-left': '220px',
                'margin-bottom': '2px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                $('.1st').animate({
                    'opacity': '0'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $('.1st').animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    })
                })
            }).fadeOut('slow');
            $('.3rd').fadeIn('slow').animate({
                'margin-bottom': '0px',
                'margin-left': '-220px'
            }, 1000, function() {
                runAnimate1 = true;
                runAnimate2 = false;
                runAnimate3 = false;
            }).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    }, 6000);
});
```

Currently this jQuery runs in a loop and give animation to different images one by one. Now, sometimes these all animations are run together and not maintain specific time interval. I want to display all animation perfectly on my browser one by one. My html is as follow..

```
<div id="outer-box" class="1st">
    <img class="1st" src="img/sofa2.jpg">
    <div id="animate1" style="display: none; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
        <img class="1st" src="img/chotu.png" style="height:300px; width:200px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="2nd 1st" style="display:none; position:absolute; bottom:0;   left:0">
        <img src="img/hand.png" style="width:200px; height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="3rd 1st" style="display:none; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0">
        <img src="img/handyh.png" style="width:180px; height: 150px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The requirement is confusing - You said **"Currently this jQuery runs one by one"** then you said **"all animations are run together and not maintain specific time interval."** then you said **"I want to display all animation perfectly on my browser one by one."**. What exactly do you want ?

Comment: I means to say that currently in this jquery, not have any issues and run successfully, but sometimes it overlaps the all animations. So, that is my main query and I want it to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
*(complete new answer)*

I've checked your script again today.

The problem comes from the fact that you use `.animate()` within the callback of an `.animate()`...
Moreover, within the callback of a callback of an `.animate()` (3rd level).

I've added some `console.log()` into [your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/3g5yuzL9/) to show that the animation **do not** occur in the order I suppose you wish it to be.
*(Hit [F12] on your keyboard to look at the console)*

Notice that the message "animation #3" appears too many times.
I suppose this is due to some internal jQuery *animation ended* event that "bubbles".

Also notice that "animation #4" appears too soon.
This is because it doesn't wait for all callback of "animation #1" to end.
It is triggered almost at the same time as "animation #1".

## So...

This animation, in my opinion, can't be achieved this way.
You better use the CSS `@keyframes`.
I made [another Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/xyp2vmpd/) to show you how.

Given there is 3 images to display one by one, 6 seconds each:
100% will then be 18 seconds.
You have to divide the 100% of the animation by 3, which is 33%.

So the first 33% is to animate the fist image.
33% to 66% for the second image.
66% to 100% for the third image.

Divide these "33%" parts achieve your animation on each image.
Like 5% to fadein, 10% to move...

Comment: I think you mean `slow` => 600ms and `fast` => 200ms not the other way around.

Comment: @KiJéy: I think my coffee did not have the expected effect this morning! Thank you for pointing this out. But it makes my first explanation slightly irrelevant. Let see what OP will tell. Thanks again.

Comment: At refresh, it animated properly but after 5 to 6 cycles of animation, it overlaps..

Comment: Do you have a live link to it? Because I looked at the CodePen for several minutes and it doesn't look like doing the behavior you describe. And without the images, it's quite boring lol!

Comment: OK I will give u fiddle link.

Comment: I will send you fiddle wait..!!

Comment: Can I mail u ? if possible..?

Comment: @Louys  you just tell me what to give instead of 6000 ? as a pause between each interval..?

Comment: Thanks a lot Louys...!!

Comment: But using css, How can we change opacity?

Comment: Louys last question..I want to run same animation in mobile device.How can I do that?

Comment: CSS runs well on any mobile device. Just use relative units (like %, em, vw and vh) instead of px.